# How to get a distinct list from a list of delimited strings

Tags: c#, linq, distinct-values, generic-collections

I have a list of delimited strings and I need to get a distinct list of the split strings.

e.g.

In: `{ "thing 1;thing 2", "thing 2;thing 3", "thing 3;thing 4" }`

Out `{ "thing 1", "thing 2", "thing 3", "thing 4" }`

This is what I have so far:

```
var delimitedThings = new List<string> { "thing 1;thing 2", "thing 2;thing 3", "thing 3;thing 4" };

var duplicatedThings = new List<string>();

foreach (var t in delimitedThings)
{
    duplicatedThings.AddRange(t.Split(';'));
}

var things = duplicatedThings.Distinct();
```

Which works, but is there a way to get `things` from `delimetedThings` in a single LINQ query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to effectively flatten a "sequence of sequences" to a single sequence - and that's what [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) is for. So your code could be written as:

```
var things = delimitedThings.SelectMany(t => t.Split(';'))
                            .Distinct();
```

Or a query expression:

```
var things = (from item in delimitedThings
              from thing in item.Split(';'))
              select thing).Distinct();
```

I certainly wouldn't use a query expression for this case, but it's instructive to know that the second (and subsequent) `from` clause in a query expression is translated as a `SelectMany` call.

Comment: @fubo beat you by 19 seconds!

Comment: @Shevek: I tried to provide a more complete and explanatory answer :)

Answer (score 2):

by using `SelectMany()` which flatens nested lists

```
var things = delimitedThings.SelectMany(x => x.Split(';')).Distinct();
```